# How to translate bytes operation to C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I would like to translate this specific code from C++ to C#. Is there a way to do that ?

```
   struct WORD_ENCR
   {
         unsigned part1 : 5;
         unsigned part2 : 4;
         unsigned part3 : 23;


         WORD_ENCR& operator =(const DWORD &a) {
                *((DWORD*) this) = a;
                return* this;
         };

   };

   DWORD wKey = 63787
   WORD_ENCR    wsResult;
   wsResult = wKey;

   unsigned int part1 = wsResult.part1;
   unsigned int part2 = wsResult.part2;
   unsigned int part3 = wsResult.part3;
```

Do you know how to reproduce that in C# ?

Thanks for your help.

---

Edit :

Many thanks for your replies.

- part1, part2 and part3 are initialized.
- DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer.

What I need to reproduce in C# is :

```
Decimal : 63787
Hexadecimal : F9 2B
Binary : 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1001 0010 1011
```

Will give :

```
part1 : 1111 100
part2 : 1 001
part3 : 0 1011
```

And finally :

```
Part1   0111 1100   7C  124
Part2   0000 1001   9   9
Part3   0000 1011   B   11
```

What I need is 124,9 and 11.

How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Could you specify the size of `int` and `DWORD` on your system?

Comment: This program doesn't look like valid C++ to me. AFAIK named bitfields need a length greater than zero. So I'd expect this program to exhibit undefined behavior. What's the expected behavior?

Comment: @MarcGravell No idea how accurate [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) is, but it says: "The value zero is only allowed for nameless bitfields and has special meaning: it specifies that the next bit field in the class definition will begin at an allocation unit's boundary"

Comment: In the absence of DWORD/int sizes, can you at least supply an example input / output? IIRC, on many systems `unsigned int` and `DWORD` are the same thing... in which case, bit-mangling here is only going to assign anything to `part1`...?

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have bit-fields. The CLR has them neither. So you need to manually do what the C compiler did for you: extract the bits using bit-level operations.

```
uint input = ...;
var part1 = input >> (4+23) & 0x1F;
var part2 = input >> (23) & 0xF;
var part3 = input >> (0) & appropriateMaskWith23OnesHere;
```

I hope I got the order of bits right, I'm not a great C developer.

Btw, all the shifts here are defined in C#. C# does not have undefined shift behavior.

Comment: oops, I've realized that I didn't fully understand the question. And also didn't know that C++ feature. wow

Comment: @christophe care to explain why?

Comment: Then maybe I got the constants wrong, but the idea is correct. Understand it and make it work. Use the debugger to find out what the individual sub-expressions evaluate to and how to fix them. This approach is correct.